# displaying navigation bar when switching to another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a button when it pressed, I want it to take me to another view (the "news" view). Within the news view, I want there to be a navigation bar with a back button. I have a navigationcontroller setup throughout my app but I can't seem to get this to work when this button is pressed. It takes me to the view I want but there is no navigation bar and no back button. This is my code that is implemented when the button is pressed.

If anybody know what I am doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
-(IBAction)news
{
newsViewController *view1 = [[newsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"newsViewController" bundle:nil];
view1.title=@"news";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view1 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: please rotate not all view but view in navigation bar, u will keep a bar and can leave control

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Can you please try explaining again? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not in my mac, so I can not test code, but if it is working and the only issue you got is not show the bar, what you need to is set the bar to be visible:

From apple docs:

> The navigation toolbar is hidden by default but you can show it for
>   your navigation interface by calling the setToolbarHidden:animated:
>   method of your navigation controller object. If not all of your view
>   controllers support toolbar items, your delegate object can call this
>   method to toggle the visibility of the toolbar during subsequent push
>   and pop operations.

Something like that is supposed to work:

```
-(IBAction)news {
    newsViewController *view1 = [[newsViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"newsViewController" bundle:nil];
    view1.title=@"news";

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view1 animated:YES];

    //Add this line!
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you! However I need a navBar not toolbar (btw toolbar was displayed at the bottom not top). I switched the code to navbar but no luck it doesn't display. Any other suggestions? thanks again

Comment: I changed the code now, sorry for my mistake, try with this new one.

Comment: Thank you ggrana but I made the change myself when I realized you had accidentally put the wrong thing. Did not work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
write the below code in page where you want to show navigation controller 
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: No Luck Cocoa, I should have mentioned I tried this before as well. Any other ideas? Thanks